# How to create a link to a page managed by Sulu?

Tags: sulu

I am using Sulu as CMS and added some pages. Additionally I have some custom Symfony actions with their own twig templates.

Now I want to add a link into the twig template that directs the user to one of the CMS pages. How can I achieve that?

I know about [`sulu-link`](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.5/bundles/markup/link.html) but what should I put into its `href` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is easier than I thought. The doc states

> The sulu-link tag allows to link to pages and other entities in the application by their id. This id of the tag will be validated and replaced by a proper anchor tag when a response is generated.

The id corresponds to the UUID of the page and you can find it in the URL, if you open the page in the admin area.

**Example**:

Open your page in the administration. Let's say its URL is `https://example.com/admin/#/webspaces/platform/pages/de/f80713e3-1e91-43b8-8351-1f3124b12878/details`

To create a link in your twig template, add this snippet:

```html
<sulu-link href="f80713e3-1e91-43b8-8351-1f3124b12878">label of my link</sulu-link>
```